# ¿Como combinar resultados de dos consultas a bases de datos diferentes y luego ordenar resultados?

Tags: php, mysql, oracle

Tengo 2 bases de datos diferentes (SQL-Server y MySQL) con los mismos campos clave, puedo obtener la información de ambas por PHP, pero me gustaria combinar dicha información para ordenarla por un campo Fecha y que quedara ordenada a la hora de mostrarla en pantalla. ¿Hay alguna forma de combinar dichas dos consultas?

Answer (score 1):

En SQL estándar puedes combinar la consulta de dos tablas de dos bases de datos separadas con un UNION.

```sql
SELECT col1, col2 FROM bd1.tabla
UNION
SELECT col1, col2 FROM bd2.tabla;
```

Para ordenar los resultados después de realizar la unión tendrías que realizarla en una subconsulta:

```sql
SELECT fecha, col1, col2
FROM (
    SELECT fecha, col1, col2 FROM bd1.tabla
    UNION
    SELECT fecha, col1, col2 FROM bd2.tabla
)
ORDER BY fecha
```

En el caso de ser de servidores diferentes lo tienes más complicado. Lo que podrías hacer es crear una tabla en tu SQL Server enlazada a tu MySQL, como comentan en este artículo: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4577/create-a-linked-server-to-mysql-from-sql-server/

Una vez logres tener la tabla que usa MySQL como fuente de datos, ¡sólo tienes que unir las dos tablas desde SQL Server!

```sql
-- En MSSQL
SELECT fecha, col1, col2
FROM (
    SELECT fecha, col1, col2 FROM tabla
    UNION
    SELECT fecha, col1, col2 FROM tabla_mysql
)
ORDER BY fecha
```